# Run Connect-MsolService concurrently

Tags: c#, multithreading, office365

I am trying to reset password for Office365 users concurrently from thread(C#).

First connect to the Office365 using *Connect-MsolService* and then reset password using *Set-MsolUserPassword* commandlets.

While executing the commandlet *Connect-MsolService*, below exception is thrown.

Exception of type 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException' was thrown.

But the user assigned in the last thread, works fine.

Whether Office365, does not support multiple connections?. Please let me know the correct way to do this concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

This error may be due to Office 365 throttling policy. How many threads are you actually running ? You should limit your thread number to 3 for the same Office 365 account.

Checkout this article about Office 365 throttling policy :
https://www.cogmotive.com/blog/office-365-tips/office-365-exchange-online-powershell-throttling